# Qual tipo de PDO::FETCH_* é o mais rápido?

Tags: php, pdo

Das que eu conheço, existem 5 maneiras de realizar, mas na [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php) é apresentado cerca de 8 maneiras diferentes de realizar um `FETCH_*`.

Gostaria de saber, de todos as maneiras de fazer um `PDO::FETCH_*`, qual é o mais rápido de se utilizar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe um script que faz um teste de velocidade: [*Benchmark Script*](https://gist.github.com/stephen-hill/5508483).

Sugiro que você execute este *benchmark* em seu próprio servidor, no entanto, este é um resultado típico na minha configuração, para resultados de uma única linha:

```
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC - 936 ms
PDO::FETCH_BOTH - 948 ms
PDO::FETCH_NUM - 1,184 ms
PDO::FETCH_OBJ - 1,272 ms
PDO::FETCH_LAZY - 1,276 ms
```

Para grandes conjuntos de dados, esses resultados são apresentados:

```
PDO::FETCH_LAZY - 5,490 ms
PDO::FETCH_NUM - 8,818 ms
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC- 10,220 ms
PDO::FETCH_BOTH - 11,359 ms
PDO::FETCH_OBJ - 14,027 ms
```